# JQuery Multiple Functions

Tags: jquery

I'm fairly new to JQuery and feel I have been picking up the code well, however, what I'm working on now has me somewhat stumped...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var tab01 = "a[href*=#web-traffic]";
var tab02 = "a[href*=#customer]";
var tab03 = "a[href*=#value]";
var tab04 = "a[href*=#fourth]";
var allTabs = '#approach .approach-tabs a';

var content01 = "#web-traffic";
var content02 = "#customer";
var content03 = "#value";
var content04 = "#fourth";


$(tab01).addClass('active');
$(content01).show();

$(tab01).on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(allTabs).removeClass('active');
});

$(tab02).on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(allTabs).removeClass('active');
});

$(tab03).on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(allTabs).removeClass('active');
});

$(tab04).on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(allTabs).removeClass('active');
});
});
```

When a link (var tab##) is clicked, I would like to add a class, 'active' and remove from all other links within the same element.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the `active` class from all tabs, and then add the class back to the clicked tab selector:

```
$(tab01).on('click', function() {
    $(allTabs).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: SimianAngel, you really are an angel! I did not know that processing order effected code, which admittedly, I should've known... Thank you so much, that did the trick.